# Dependent text value based on dropdown generated for each record

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

[image]

Hi Good day! So I have this dropdown on "Cause of Failure" and I would like to have it autopopulate values on the Category and Setup Status boxes based on the selected value on Cause of Failure. The input boxes and select boxes appears based on the amount of records this php code returns (). So far I have the code below to automatically populate the other two boxes however It only works on the row but not on the others. How Do I make it apply to all rows?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cofailure').change(function(){
    var cofailure = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({ 
      url: 'ajax/fetchcategory.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {cofailure: cofailure},
      success: function(data){  
        $('#category').val(data);
      }
    });

    $.ajax({ 
      url: 'ajax/fetchstatus.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {cofailure: cofailure},
      success: function(data){
        $('#setupstatus').val(data);
      }
    }); 


    $.ajax({ 
      url: 'ajax/fetchendstat.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {cofailure: cofailure},
      success: function(data){
        $('#resolutionstatus').val(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Consider selecting elements based on a class instead of an id. Many elements can have the same class, but ids are meant to be unique to one element.

Comment: So if I use class for example for the selectbox, if i add an event listener and use class for the inputs I would like to autopopulate, how does it know which inputs it would autopopulate if i willl be using class as well for the inputs?

Comment: Please help ='c

Comment: badly need help on this ='c

Comment: Please ='c ......

Comment: @RobMoll Please help ='c